# Service similar to Ubuntu One

Tags: backup, ubuntu-one

Since the Ubuntu One service has been closed, is any new location or service is being provided by Ubuntu for backup?

Comment: related: [What are the alternatives to Ubuntu One?](//askubuntu.com/q/442430)

Answer (score 3):

No there is no Ubuntu-provided service for this.  Dropbox and others still exist however, but they are not run by Canonical or Ubuntu.

Comment: I'm using syncthing: http://apt.syncthing.net/

Comment: @elopio Thats still not an Ubuntu-run thing - the question asks "is any new location or service being provided by Ubuntu for backup", which means that my answer stands that there's no ubuntu provided solutoin for this, and anything that could do it is third-party.